# Is there a method to what pattern is displayed when no profile picture is set?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

Is there a method to what pattern is displayed when no profile picture is set? I noticed different patterns for different people.

Comment: Are you talking about the [gravatars](http://en.gravatar.com)?

Comment: Yes, I was. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generated by [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) automatically in the absence of an image, whatever method they use is on that side (as opposed to SO doing it).  It works by taking your email (the one you provided to the SO/SE site) and making an md5 hash of it, it then just turns that into a URL, like this:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/17878cd922587630c7a75ca2e0e0b177?d=identicon
```

With that `d=identicon` is on there (or `default=identicon`) you get a random semi-unique generated image, like this:

[image]

If it's not on there, you get the generic gravatar icon:

[image]

[The only description they give for this](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) is:

- **identicon**: a geometric pattern based on an email hash

So the method is ultimately your email address being translated into an image based on the hash of it...how *exactly* they do this it doesn't say.

Comment: But this was helpful.

Comment: also, if they don't provide an email, it's a hash of their last known IP address

Comment: Is it just me, or are these image links broken?

Comment: -1 for broken images http://i.imgur.com/IN7Es.png and http://i.imgur.com/PGEo5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can actually change which pattern is displayed by changing the hash in the URL and change the size by varying the number after the `s=` part.

Try fiddling around with different numbers in the hash to see the different colors and patterns that are generated for your liking.

For example:

> http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/74ed89d655616683e90d16569b171a01.jpg?d=identicon&r=r&**s=83**

change it to

> http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/74ed89d655616683e90d16569b171337.jpg?d=identicon&r=r&**s=9001**